# No wired or wireless connection after installation

Tags: wifi, system, networking, drivers, internet

After installing Elementary OS 7.1 (Hour), there is no wired or WIFI access to the Internet. EOS7.1 on the laptop is the second operating system.

If you try to connect a wired cable, the Network slider is activated, but there is no Internet access.

I tried to solve this problem, but I didn't get any results.
I would appreciate your help!

```
uname -r
6.2.0-33-generic

**Laptop equipment:**
Neobihier
Intel Core i7-1195G7 (2.9 GHz),
RAM 64 GB,
SSD 2048 GB,
NVIDIA GeForce MX450 (2 GB)
```

I am attaching a photo from the laptop screen.
[image]

===

!!! UPD

I reinstalled the OS. I thought the problem was an incorrect installation. But after installation the WiFi module disappeared. The wired connection setup also disappeared. Strange.

Could you help me?

I attached a photo of the screen.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue yesterday. This happened after I did an update, not sure which one. You need to reinstall the linux-modules-extra package.

Download this using a different system and save it to a USB:

[http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-hwe-6.2/linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-33-generic_6.2.0-33.33~22.04.1_amd64.deb](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-hwe-6.2/linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-33-generic_6.2.0-33.33%7E22.04.1_amd64.deb)

Copy it from the USB to the broken system and install it:

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-33-generic_6.2.0-33.33~22.04.1_amd64.deb
```

Reboot and you should be good.

Comment: Thank you for your help! But my problem was not solved.

Let me add, maybe the problem is that I have to boot the OS through recovery mode. And therefore it does not provide the opportunity to load all modules/drivers.

I can't directly boot into the OS. I have an ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol. And after this error "Power down". There is no update for BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help! But my problem was not solved.

Let me add, maybe the problem is that I have to boot the OS through recovery mode. And therefore it does not provide the opportunity to load all modules/drivers.

I can't directly boot into the OS. I have an ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol. And after this error "Power down". There is no update for BIOS.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Magic!

I reinstalled the OS, connected the Internet via a USB modem. Wired Internet appeared.

Now the problem is with the Internet via WiFi.